# Error message with p:treetable javax.faces.FacesException: treeTable's value must be null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm migrating from 3.5 to 7.0. In 7.0 `p:treetable` is giving me the error mentioned in the title and prevents our application from working normally. First I thought that they where saying that probably treetable value is null so I checked if the treetable was null but it wasn't, and I spent hours trying to make it null, but still the error persists (even though we were sure it was null, even made it null on the getter method but it had no sense).

Comment: These are not questions for stavkoverflow. It is not even a question, more a statement. Please file an issue in the PrimeFaces github

Comment: @Kukeltje yooo dude, yes okay but don't you agree that message should say NOT be null?

Comment: @Kukeltje also mate now in PrimeFaces 7.0 treetable has an empty message which is destroying my screen because I have one treetable above another one, the above one is empty is just a header, so that empty message is giving problems and I did set up the emptyMessage="" but still looks ugly, do you know if there is a way to make it not have emptyMessage?

Comment: @Kukeltje don't downvote me mate or I won't be able to ask more things and I think this questions about the migration are helping improve if someone does the same in the future :)

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast Please file an issue here https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues - there's really no answer for this "question".

Comment: @Kukeltje I can't post questions now mate

Comment: Then change the question in to a question with a [MCVE] and the original error text and create an answer where you state the error text is wrong and that your code was right. Then the downvote will be removed. But I cannot imagine that just two downvotes blocks you asking questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th Also not the 'ip address' thing, so bad questions from colleagues count too if they come from the same ip address!)

Comment: @Kukeltje remove it bro I will just delete it and go post to primefaces github ;p

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast Also note that a downvote can't be removed unless the question itself is edited first.

Comment: I edited it and made the part of the question that was the answer into an answer. I also removed my downvote. You may copy my answer into your own and I'll remove mine... But please create an issue with PF and next time also create an [mcve].

Comment: @Kukeltje Okay bro thank you! I will next time :) I can post questions now but I have a warning that says it better be a very well made question lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We eventually gave up and looked at the showcase and saw that they initialize the `p:treetable` on the postconstruct, so I did the same and the screen finally rendered, so my partner and I think or came to the conclusion that the error we get is wrong and perhaps it should say

```
javax.faces.FacesException: treeTable's value must NOT be null.
```

to avoid confusion.

Most likely we had some error that initially made it null and resulted in the error which put us off on the wrong foot.

Comment: I added an issue in PrimeFaces: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5474

Comment: For me I had a bean hierarchy, that is beans extending from framework classes and I forgot to remove the `abstract` modifier from the implementing  leaf classes... yuk